# Why does a Scala for-comprehension have to start with a generator?

Tags: scala, haskell, monads

According to the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (§6.19), "An enumerator sequence always starts with a generator". Why?

I sometimes find this restriction to be a hindrance when using `for`-comprehensions with monads, because it means you can't do things like this:

```
def getFooValue(): Future[Int] = {
  for {
    manager = Manager.getManager() // could throw an exception
    foo <- manager.makeFoo() // method call returns a Future
    value = foo.getValue()
  } yield value
}
```

Indeed, `scalac` rejects this with the error message `'<-' expected but '=' found`.

If this was valid syntax in Scala, one advantage would be that any exception thrown by `Manager.getManager()` would be caught by the `Future` monad used within the `for`-comprehension, and would cause it to yield a failed `Future`, which is what I want. The workaround of moving the call to `Manager.getManager()` outside the `for`-comprehension doesn't have this advantage:

```
def getFooValue(): Future[Int] = {
  val manager = Manager.getManager()

  for {
    foo <- manager.makeFoo()
    value = foo.getValue()
  } yield value
}
```

In this case, an exception thrown by `foo.getValue()` will yield a failed `Future` (which is what I want), but an exception thrown by `Manager.getManager()` will be thrown back to the caller of `getFooValue()` (which is not what I want). Other possible ways of handling the exception are more verbose.

I find this restriction especially puzzling because in Haskell's otherwise similar `do` notation, there is no requirement that a `do` block should begin with a statement containing `<-`. Can anyone explain this difference between Scala and Haskell?

Here's a complete working example showing how exceptions are caught by the `Future` monad in `for`-comprehensions:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

class Foo(val value: Int) {
  def getValue(crash: Boolean): Int = {
    if (crash) {
      throw new Exception("failed to get value")
    } else {
      value
    }
  }
}

class Manager {
  def makeFoo(crash: Boolean): Future[Foo] = {
    if (crash) {
      throw new Exception("failed to make Foo")
    } else {
      Future(new Foo(10))
    }
  }
}

object Manager {
  def getManager(crash: Boolean): Manager = {
    if (crash) {
      throw new Exception("failed to get manager")
    } else {
      new Manager()
    }
  }
}

object Main extends App {

  def getFooValue(crashGetManager: Boolean,
                  crashMakeFoo: Boolean,
                  crashGetValue: Boolean): Future[Int] = {
    for {
      manager <- Future(Manager.getManager(crashGetManager))
      foo <- manager.makeFoo(crashMakeFoo)
      value = foo.getValue(crashGetValue)
    } yield value
  }

  def waitForValue(future: Future[Int]): Unit = {
    val result = Try(Await.result(future, Duration("10 seconds")))
    result match {
      case Success(value) => println(s"Got value: $value")
      case Failure(e) => println(s"Got error: $e")
    }
  }

  val future1 = getFooValue(false, false, false)
  waitForValue(future1)
  val future2 = getFooValue(true, false, false)
  waitForValue(future2)
  val future3 = getFooValue(false, true, false)
  waitForValue(future3)
  val future4 = getFooValue(false, false, true)
  waitForValue(future4)
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Got value: 10
Got error: java.lang.Exception: failed to get manager
Got error: java.lang.Exception: failed to make Foo
Got error: java.lang.Exception: failed to get value
```

This is a trivial example, but I'm working on a project in which we have a lot of non-trivial code that depends on this behaviour. As far as I understand, this is one of the main advantages of using `Future` (or `Try`) as a monad. What I find strange is that I have to write

```
manager <- Future(Manager.getManager(crashGetManager))
```

instead of

```
manager = Manager.getManager(crashGetManager)
```

(Edited to reflect @RexKerr's point that the monad is doing the work of catching the exceptions.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`for` comprehensions **do not catch exceptions**.  `Try` does, and it has the appropriate methods to participate in for-comprehensions, so you can

```
for {
  manager <- Try { Manager.getManager() }
  ...
}
```

But then it's expecting `Try` all the way down unless you manually or implicitly have a way to switch container types (e.g. something that converts `Try` to a `List`).

So I'm not sure your premises are right.  Any assignment you made in a for-comprehension can just be made early.

(Also, there is no point doing an assignment inside a for comprehension just to yield that exact value.  Just do the computation in the yield block.)

(Also, just to illustrate that multiple types can play a role in `for` comprehensions so there's not a super-obvious correct answer for how to wrap an early assignment in terms of later types:

```
// List and Option, via implicit conversion
for {i <- List(1,2,3); j <- Option(i).filter(_ <2)} yield j

// Custom compatible types with map/flatMap
// Use :paste in the REPL to define A and B together
class A[X] { def flatMap[Y](f: X => B[Y]): A[Y] = new A[Y] }
class B[X](x: X) { def map[Y](f: X => Y): B[Y] = new B(f(x)) }
for{ i <- (new A[Int]); j <- (new B(i)) } yield j.toString
```

Even if you take the first type you still have the problem of whether there is a unique "bind" (way to wrap) and whether to doubly-wrap things that are already the correct type.  There could be rules for all these things, but for-comprehensions are already hard enough to learn, no?)

Comment: doing the assignment in the for comprehension can make sense to split an rhs expression that would be too long/complex and help readbility. just the same as introducing a local variable within a map/flatmap. Having to do so may be a sign of trouble with the design but it can still be helpful :)

Comment: Exceptions are indeed caught in for-comprehensions when used with Future or Try monads. Try it yourself, you'll see. I agree that I could wrap my call to Manager.getManager() in a Future or Try constructor, and I guess this is probably the best workaround. But I don't see why I should have to. And yes, as @Jean notes, for-comprehensions often need to do lots of calculations that would be far too long to put in the yield block.

Comment: @Jean - You can execute multi-line statements in the yield block too.  There may be some cases where splitting it up is clearer, though.

Comment: @BenjaminGeer - The for-comprehension isn't catching anything.  The monad is doing all the work.  So you want the compiler to guess which monad you meant to wrap your initial assignment in?  And what if it's already the right type?  Wrap again anyway or not?  You _could_ come up with consistent rules for these things, but I think being explicit (unambiguous) should win out here.  Besides: what is `Manager.getManager()` doing returning a non-monad anyway?  That's where the problem really lies.  If your methods aren't "properly" typed, I'm not sure a quick explicit wrapping is so bad.

Comment: @RexKerr OK, strictly speaking, the monad is doing all the work, but I think you're splitting hairs. Why couldn't the for-comprehension get the monad's type from the first generator provided (or any generator, since they all have to be the same type), even if it's not the first statement in the for-comprehension?

Comment: @RexKerr The reason that `Manager.getManager()` returns a non-monad is, for example, because it's provided by a third-party Java library, and I have no control over what it returns.

Comment: @BenjaminGeer - Any type that "works", via availability of `map`/`flatMap` of appropriate signature or implicit conversion, is allowed in a for-comprehension.  So it's not necessarily so obvious what the type is.  You also open up subtle bugs caused by e.g. dropping a `toOption` onto part of the code (suddenly, no more catching!).  Also, if you use libraries that are dangerous in ways that your normal code is not, having a `Try` or whatnot as a warning is more of an advantage than disadvantage!  So although it's _possible_ to have a for-comprehension work this way, it seems unwise to me.

Comment: I agree that it would be nice if you could specify the type of a for-comprehension explicitly. I try to keep it clear via coding style: when using a monad, I generally write a method whose entire body is a for-comprehension, and whose return type is the monad, which is the result of the `yield`. Since we have to use Futures constantly anyway (because of Akka), for-comprehensions make the code vastly simpler than it would otherwise be. But the price to pay is syntactic restrictions like the one I'm asking about. Hence I wonder whether these restrictions are really necessary.

Comment: @BenjaminGeer - It isn't _really_ necessary, but it is a good idea for contexts which are more mixed than yours.  It could have been implemented differently: `for` requires a `M[A] <: Monad[A]` and requires all items to be the same type, at which point the early definition would be unproblematic.  But there was a different choice made (more flexibility), so at this point I think it _would_ be inadvisable to change as the danger of accidental confusion or bugs is high.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell translates the equivalent of `for { manager = Manager.getManager(); ... }` to the equivalent of `lazy val manager = Manager.getManager(); for { ... }`. This seems to work:

```
scala> lazy val x: Int = throw new Exception("")
x: Int = <lazy>

scala> for { y <- Future(x + 1) } yield y
res8: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@fedb05d

scala> Try(Await.result(res1, Duration("10 seconds")))
res9: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.Exception: )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason this can't be done is because for-loops are syntactic sugar for *flatMap* and *map* methods (except if you are using a condition in the for-loop, in that case it's desugared with the method *withFilter*). When you are storing in a immutable variable, you can't use these methods. That's the reason you would be ok using **Try** as pointed out by Rex Kerr. In that case, you should be able to use *map* and *flatMap* methods.

Comment: As far as I understand, Haskell's do notation is also syntactic sugar for similar function calls (Scala's flatMap is analogous to Haskell's bind). So why can't Scala's for-comprehensions offer the same flexibility as Haskell's do notation?